# Php Undefined Index Error On Login And Member Page

Tags: php

OK so i am new to php and i am having a error with my log in and member page here is the code. I don't know why i have this error any help with me greatly appreciated please comment as soon as possible.

LOGIN PHP PAGE

```
<?php

session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username&&$password)
{
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Couldn't Connect!");
    mysql_select_db("phplogin") or die("Couldn't Find DB!");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$username."'");

    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($numrows!=0)
    {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $dbusername = $row['username'];
            $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        }

        // check to see if they match!
        if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
        {
            echo "Your're in! <a href='member.php'>Click</a> here to enter the member page.";
            $_SESSION['username']==$dbusername;
        }
        else
            echo "Incorrect password!";

    }
    else
        die("That user doesn't exist");

}
else
    die("Please enter and username and password!");
?>
```

MEMBER PHP PAGE

```
<?php

session_start();

echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!";

?>
```

INDEX PHP PAGE

```
<html>
    <form action="login.php" method="POST">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br />
        <input type="submit" name="Login In"><br />
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: add the entire error text, we would need to know which variable is undefined.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable with a SQL-injection.

Comment: change `$_SESSION['username']==$dbusername;` to `$_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;`

Comment: storing plain text passwords!? oh yeah!

Comment: EVERYTHING in your code is wrong. With all respect, please delete your entire code and get a professional login script or a professional framework. You are reinventing the wheel, with awful code that doesn't even work and is hacked in milliseconds.

Comment: @mjayt even if it was as an example.

Comment: Its not wrong, its just not very good. Keep trying and improving user3033100. Heres a nice tutorial for beginners if u got the time: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kyQGBABA38&list=PLE134D877783367C7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mysql is depreciated, you should use mysqli or PDO. 
One thing I noticed is on $_SESSION['username']==$dbusername; shouldn't it be only 1 equals? As your assigning $dbusername to the $_SESSION['username'] variable.

Comment: I need 50 reputation to comment on other peoples posts. sorry for putting in answers

Comment: ty :P I can now stop spaming answers and spam comments instead :)

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning a value without checking if they really exist:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

If I'm right, it'll solve:

```
$username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$password = !empty($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
```

Comment: Still getting the rror with this method you posted

Answer (score -1):

You're doing way too much in PHP here.

`query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password=PASSWORD('$password');`

done, if there's a result, the user is in. If the set is empty, the username or password was wrong. Now you won't know whether the username or password is wrong: *GREAT*! You should not tell users that their password is wrong, because someone can try to get into your system by just guessing names until your system changes from "that username doesn't exist" to "that password doesn't exist". Bingo, now we know that username exists and we can just start mashing passwords to see if the common ones work.

Oh, and store those passwords hashed. Use `PASSWORD(password)` or something when you `INSERT` them. You have no right to know what they are, you don't need the actual password to compare, and it's not exactly a password if anyone can just look at your database and have a full copy of all usernames and associated plain text passwords.

Comment: that undefined index is either irrelevant if we can cut out half the PHP code, or it's still the case and then good news, we just removed half the code, now it's much easier to find.

Comment: http://www.warmenhoven.co/2012/03/06/do-not-use-md5-or-sha1-to-simply-hash-db-passwords/

Comment: It's not irrelevant, that's the question title. And it's still right here `$username = $_POST['username'];`

Comment: @mjayt good point, changed to the built in `PASSWORD` function

Comment: this answer doesn't address his actual question, very true. It does address multiple problems, and as such is worth giving. The more you know. Downvoting it as "not the right answer" is kind of weird in this case (note that the votes are for useful answers, not correct answers. that's what the OP gets to pick that checkmark for)

Comment: I didn't realise tangential advice should be posted as an actual answer. I may be wrong but I'm not sure that it should.

Comment: Pretty sure I've seen plenty of them posted, many of them valued for being posted and upvoted because they were useful.

Comment: Ok. But in the list of questions won't it show there is an answer, and might people who can answer the question skip those questions?